# NetLogo let target min-one-of neighbors math operation produced a non-number

Tags: netlogo

I am new to NetLogo and I am trying to reproduce https://github.com/YangZhouCSS/Pedestrian_Model_Krasnow.  When I open, it says that it was produced in NetLogo 5.2 and I am running NetLogo 6.3 so I may need to update code.  When I try to run I get a math operation produced a non-number on the following line in the to go section:

```html
let target min-one-of neighbors [ elevation + ( count turtles-here * 9999999) ]
```

This is the complete to go section:

```html
to go
  if count turtles > 0 [set move-speed count turtles with [moved? = true] / count turtles]
  if count turtles = 0 [stop]

  ask patches with [exit = 1] [ask turtles-here[die]]

  ask turtles [
    set moved? false
    let target min-one-of neighbors [ elevation + ( count turtles-here * 9999999) ]

    if [elevation + (count turtles-here * 9999999)] of target < [elevation] of patch-here
    [ face target
      move-to target
      set moved? true
      ask target [set path path + 1]]
  ]

  if Show_path? [ask patches with [elevation < 9999999][let thecolor (9.9 - (path * 0.15)) if thecolor < 0.001 [set thecolor 0.001] set pcolor thecolor]]
  tick
end
```

And the complete code is here:  https://github.com/YangZhouCSS/Pedestrian_Model_Krasnow/blob/master/pedestrian_floor-2exits.nlogo

Thank you in advance for any guidance

Answer (score 1):

Many of the patches have invalid (NaN) values for their `elevation`, which then causes the error you are getting when you try to use them in an arithmetic operation.  I'm not conversant in the gis extension, so I can't tell you why it seems to be assigning invalid elevations to these patches, but if you run setup and then enter in the command center

```
ask patches [show elevation]
```

you will see which ones are invalid and may then be able to trace how they came to be that way.  Perhaps the gis extension has changed the way it works with the data files since NetLogo v5?

Charles

Comment: Thanks Charles. Much appreciated on the guidance. Doing what you say, I do see the NaN values for most of their elevations. Will look into that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure why it worked but I replaced

```
let target min-one-of neighbors [ elevation + ( count turtles-here * 9999999) ]
```

With

```
let target min-one-of neighbors [ elevation ]
```

And the simulation ran

Comment: It works because you no longer are trying to use a non-number (NaN) elevation in an arithmetic expression.  If you want to remain true to the original model, you can use

let target min-one-of (neighbors with [elevation >= 0]) [ elevation + ( count turtles-here * 9999999) ]

Since valid elevations are always >= 0, the addition will only be applied to neighbors with a valid elevation.  Now I am not sure why the >= operator can be applied to a NaN, but apparently it can.  I'd suggest that you work out why GIS is assigning NaN to certain cells.  Perhaps an older version used 9999999 instead?